# Unable to figure out how to use navigator with Jssor Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

Sorry but even with all the help at the website, I still can't seem to get the navigator to work on my page.  I've got the following html:

```
<div id="bj3dd" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <div data-slides="" u="slides" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="jssora03l" u="arrowleft"></span>
    <span class="jssora03r" u="arrowright"></span>
    <div class="jssort03" u="thumbnavigator" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 60px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

With the following js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {

        $AutoPlay: true,                                    
        $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
        $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,
        $DragOrientation: 1,
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 1,
            $AutoCenter: 0,
            $Steps: 1
        },
        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2,
        }

    };
    new $JssorSlider$('bj3dd', options);
});
```

Try as I might, I can't get the navigator to work, please put me out of my misery and tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="bj3dd" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <div data-slides="" u="slides" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg">
            <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Open 'skin\arrow-03.source.html' and copy arrow navigator skin here -->
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

    <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Open 'skin\thumbnail-03.source.html' and copy thumbnail navigator skin here -->
    <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->
</div>
```